# Microchip MRF24WN0MB datasheet for use in STM32

Tags: stm32, driver, datasheet, microchip

We have designed a board where a [Microchip MRF24WN0MB](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MRF24WN0MB) WiFi is connected to an [STM32L082](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32l082cz.html) ARM micro-controller through SPI.

I can generate code with STM32CubeMX (compiled with Eclipse SW4STM32) and run it on the board, and I wanted to start the Microchip WiFi but I can't seem to find any datasheet explaining basic things like initialization, configuration, registers, etc. The [datasheet they provide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002410A.pdf) gives the electrical configurations but nothing about programming it.

There are many references on their website to "MPLAB Harmony", which I downloaded. I found reference to MRF24WN drivers in the `framework/driver/wifi/mrf24wn` but no documentation on how to integrate it on my board.

Is there an official datasheet with those information? Or a somehow-documented standalone driver I could compile and use?

Comment: Asking a question forces self-questioning. I found some documentation in `doc/html/16815.html` (Harmony_help_Volum_V_part_I.pdf).

Comment: http://microchipdeveloper.com/wifi:wh

 May also be of some assistance to you.

Comment: @isdi thanks, but I'm already using STM32CubeMX+SW4STM32-Eclipse as an IDE and would like to avoid getting too many different IDE (i.e. not go through MPLAB Harmony). But I'll give it a try though, it's better than what I have right now...

Comment: Yes, you may be able to inspect their simple demo project and translate to Eclipse to get the basics going.  I'm involved with one project now that has spent the bulk of it's time on getting everything working robustly -outside- of the actual device such as connection drops, retries, cloud disconnect, phone apps, etc.  It is a difficult thing to do correctly and it's different for every project.  That's why you generally get an API only from the manufacturer along with a simple demo; the rest keeps firmware guys in business :-)

Comment: @isdi X-D. Well, I might switch to a simpler device then. LoRa was already taking up too much time so I wanted to switch to WiFi, but now I guess I have bluetooth as a last resort... (I might start seeing why we packed so many different chips on that board ;))

Comment: Yep, years ago we used an RN171 (also microchip now) that basically was a table driven (command mode was an escape character sequence) UART interface.  Made for really simple connections, as it did the whole WiFi/TCP/UDP connection, -but- we went through a lot of grief with their firmware updates (bug exchanges, bricked units, failed OTA updates, etc.)  I think some chip makers learned their lesson and backed off from that solution strategy.  That experience was enough to bite the bullet and do the application development in-house on the next project (using TI CCS,  a whole other nightmare :-)